# Facebook Like button

Tags: facebook

I build new web site. On every post in my web site I have facebook Like button.
When visitor click on like button post don't appear on his-user home page , only in his profile page.

Can someone tell me why post(like) don't appear on home page?

I use code generated from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like (iframe)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember running into this problem several months ago.  This solved the problem for me (then), but the situation may have changed by now.  Just put the meta data in the head with the desired info.  It may take a while for facebook to notice that you have changed anything.

```
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Lime" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Lime Title" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="With more and more Lime [...]" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/" />
  <!--meta property="fb:page_id" content="18807449704" /-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the news feed in the facebook user's home page?!
It's not used to show the user's actions, [read this](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=408):

> News Feed — the center column of your
>   home page — is a constantly updating
>   list of stories from people and Pages
>   that you follow on Facebook.